# Can a transgender( Female to male) get married to a muslim female?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, nikah, sex, transgender

I’m a muslim female & I’m planning to go through the hormone therapy and all that process to become a male. So after the whole process (which would take years) can I get married to a female? Does islam allow me to marry a girl?

Comment: This might depend on whether you get [phalloplasty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phalloplasty) or not.

Comment: @G.Bach i will get phalloplasty surgery.

Comment: This will depend on the school of thought, and your present physiology. *Some may* allow you to change and marry if there is a demonstrable cause, e.g the physical presence of both genitalia.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requires a personalized fatwa.

Answer (score -1):

Transgender is not allowed in Islam, so no you can´t.

Qoute from the Quran "And made of him two mates, the male and the female."

source: https://quran.com/75/39

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Answers should be elaborate and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour] in the [help], and refer to [answer].